# Random forest on compound analysis and input data permutation

Tags: random-forest, joint-distribution, permutation-test, compound-distributions

I am using a random forest model to associate climate variables with a specific type of impact, which is measured as the likelihood of failure (therefore, classification). The choice of random forest is due to working well with non-linear conditions, such as tipping points or thresholds, no need to standardise the variables (temperature in Kelvin and precipitation in mm) and its interoperability.

Yet, parallel to the RF model, I am analysing the data from a compound perspective as well. That is, I select a boundary for extreme climatic values (>90th, <10th) and measure the joint-occurrence of these variables along the time series and then compare the result with a similar joint-occurrence of the same variables but randomly shuffled (permuted). For the sake of simplicity, I have taken the comparison using only two variables and plotted graphs along. Given the high correlation the two variables present, it is natural to infer that permutation plays a meaningful role in the joint-occurrence, as it can be seen from the figures. Simply put: the conditions for a failure to happen increase when the data is correlated.
[image: shuffled data]
[image: correlated data]

However, when predicting the number of failures with the shuffled data, it is actually rather surprising to notice the values do not change at all. From that, I wonder if 1) the RF model is trained already shuffling or permuting the data (perhaps the bootstrap step could be related to this?) or if it is just too naive to account for the "compound effect" as I'm calling right now. I wonder if anyone could provide any input on this matter and if there is anything wrong with my experiment, or if there is any solutions and alternatives to the situation. Also, I could try other classifiers as well should it be the case.

I appreciate any help.

Best,

Henrique